# Error importing MS Access table to SAS

Tags: ms-access, sas

When I use the Import Data wizard in SAS Enterprise Guide, I'm getting the following error. Any ideas why? Thanks!

[image: Error message]

Comment: Seems like the error tells you the issue.  If you run SAS in Unicode mode, does that fix the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what "Unicode mode" means.

Comment: If you are running base SAS 9.3 or later you likely have a Unicode mode installed. Look in your shortcuts in the SAS start menu folder. Otherwise ask your SAS admin.

Comment: Oh ok I'm actually running SAS Enterprise Guide, not base SAS. Is there a way to identify which field contains the characters that are causing the error?

Comment: If you're running EG against a server, then you should talk to your admins.